# Should the translation-methodology and translation-philosophy tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [translation-philosophy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-philosophy) described as:

> The philosophical basis that grounds the work of translators. Questions about specific translation problems should instead be tagged hebrew, aramaic, or greek as appropriate.

It has two synonyms, [translation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) and [translation-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-approaches).  We also have [translation-methodology](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-methodology) which has no description.  There is an active [proposal](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/translation-philosophy/synonyms) to merge the two.

Ignoring that both tags are probably on questions they shouldn't be, is there a reason to have two tags or should they be merged?  "approaches" would seem to be more of a synonym for "methodology" than "philosophy" so that perhaps suggests "yes" based on precedent.  However, I am not convinced they are really the same thing.

That is, I'm not sure "philosophy" is really the best all-encompassing term, if that is indeed the way we want to go.  Perhaps we can come up with a better term to capture all the "meta aspects" of translation?

Thoughts?